# How does one grant an application exclusive access to the Windows registry?

Tags: windows, windows-7, permissions, windows-registry

My company uses a line-of-business application with a peculiar requirement. This software's purpose is to manage data collected by a personnel electrostatic discharge test machine (i.e., poll the machine for data, update user test status, send out scheduled reports, etc.). To function properly, it requires uninterrupted, constant access to the Windows registry.

A slew of issues has cropped up. The software becomes unresponsive, fails to update user status, fails to send out scheduled reports, etc. with no error messages whatsoever. The software's support team says that this is symptomatic of registry access being interrupted by some other process, and that this typically happens when Windows Updates or anti-virus scans are run.

We've disabled anti-virus and Windows Updates entirely. The computer that runs this software is unattended and used for no other purpose than to run this software.

How can I ensure that this application has uninterrupted access to the Windows registry? Is this possible?

Comment: I think they're giving you a line of bull. The registry is in constant use by applications and processes. I've never heard of a process or application interrupting the registry access of another process or application. Might they mean "unrestricted" access?

Comment: Additionally, you cannot grant an application "exclusive" access to the registry.

Comment: Thanks. I've posted this elsewhere and the consensus seems to be that it's nonsense. I think I will run ProcMon and show them nothing is touching their registry keys.